# How can I manually add suggestions in code reviews on GitHub?

Tags: github

In GitHub it's possible to [suggest code changes](https://blog.github.com/changelog/2018-10-16-suggested-changes/) through inline comments in pull requests. But I always get the following error message: "suggestions cannot be applied while viewing a subset of changes".

Is there also a way to manually suggest changes in a comment?

Example: [image: screenshot of problem]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Besides the toolbar-button you can also add a suggestion within a comment by

- **markdown syntax**, using a fenced code block with language `suggestion` like:

  ````
  ```suggestion
  this is my new suggestion
  ```
  ````
- **shortcut**, pressing <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> (Mac) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> (Windows/Linux)

Comment: keyboard shortcut:  Ctrl+G  -  https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/using-github/keyboard-shortcuts

Answer (score 8):

How-to **code suggest to multiple lines**

Apply a code suggestion to multiple lines by highlight dragging the code lines. Starting drag to the right of the line numbers where the comment plus icon appears.

[image: Start dragging]

Verify by seeing "Commenting on lines +129 to +145" (or similar) text indicating the multiple line range you are commenting on.

[image: Verify step]

Now the code suggestion will replace more than one line!